# TYPO3 - Flexforms displayCond not working

Tags: php, typo3

I'm trying to display a conditional field, with the condition being a checked checkbox. 
This is the display condition:

```
<displayCond>FIELD:isEvent:=:1</displayCond>
```

Could anyone help me out? This is the full code:

```
 <T3DataStructure>
  <sheets>
        <sDEF>
              <ROOT>
                    <TCEforms>
                          <sheetTitle>Function</sheetTitle>
                    </TCEforms>
                    <type>array</type>
                    <el>
                          <settings.priceList>
                                <section>1</section>
                                <type>array</type>
                                <el>
                                      <container>
                                            <title>Price boxes</title>
                                            <type>array</type>
                                            <el>
                                                  <name>
                                                        <TCEforms>
                                                              <label>Seasons name</label>
                                                              <config>
                                                                    <type>input</type>
                                                                    <size>48</size>
                                                              </config>
                                                        </TCEforms>
                                                  </name>
                                                  <isEvent>                   
                                                        <TCEforms>
                                                              <exclude>0</exclude>
                                                              <label>Is event?</label>
                                                              <config>
                                                                    <type>check</type>
                                                              </config>
                                                        </TCEforms>
                                                  </isEvent>
                                                  <evenText>
                                                        <TCEforms type="array">
                                                              <exclude>0</exclude>
                                                              <label>Event text</label>
                                                              <displayCond>FIELD:isEvent:=:1</displayCond>
                                                              <config type="array">
                                                                    <type>text</type>
                                                                    <cols>48</cols>
                                                                    <rows>5</rows>
                                                              </config>
                                                              <defaultExtras>richtext[*]:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css]</defaultExtras>
                                                        </TCEforms>
                                                  </evenText>

                                            </el>
                                      </container>
                                </el>
                          </settings.priceList>
                    </el>
              </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
  </sheets>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is not supported for `container` elements, only on the top level.
There's no way to specify the index of a container element, there's no context for this in the method that evaluates the condition.

`settings.isEvent` would work, but something like
`settings.priceList.container.0.isEvent` is not supported.

You can take a look at the code of `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProvider\EvaluateDisplayConditions::matchFieldCondition` yourself to clarify.